# VueJS, Change font weight without increasing container size in a dynamic label

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm making the template of a checkbox, with a label that can contain any string. When I make the label bold, the whole div gets increased. And I'm looking for a way to prevent this. I can't use workarounds like using shadow to emulate the bold font unfortunately.

Any idea?

The checkbox:

```
<template>
    <label
        class="container"
        :class="[
            props.vertical && 'flex-col',
            props.vertical && props.reversed && 'flex-col-reverse',
            !props.vertical && props.reversed && 'flex-row-reverse',
            props.disabled && 'opacity-30',
        ]"
    >
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center m-2">
            <input
                class="w-6 h-6 opacity-0"
                :value="props.modelValue"
                :disabled="props.disabled"
                type="checkbox"
                @change="updateValue"
            />
            <span class="mark" :class="[props.disabled && 'opacity-30']"> </span>
        </div>
        <span class="label" :class="labelClasses">
            {{ props.label }}
        </span>
    </label>
</template>
```

The styling (applied classes are TailwindCSS)

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .container {
        @apply flex justify-center items-center relative cursor-pointer text-gray-dark text-base;
    }

    /* Hide the original checkbox */
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /* creating a custom checkbox*/
    .mark {
        @apply absolute top-0 left-0 w-6 h-6 border-[0.0625rem] bg-white border-gray-dark rounded-[0.3125rem];
    }

    /*border style when the checkbox is checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .mark {
        @apply border-2;
    }

    /* checklabel to be shown in checkbox */
    /* It will not be shown when unchecked */
    .mark:after {
        @apply content-[""] absolute hidden;
    }

    /* display checklabel when checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .mark:after {
        @apply block;
    }

    /* creating a square to be the mark of checklabel */
    .container .mark:after {
        @apply left-1 bottom-1 w-3 h-3 rounded-sm bg-gray-dark;
    }

    .label {
        @apply block;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the font weight of the label changes when the checkbox is clicked. I think the only way you can prevent the div from getting wider is by adding a fixed with to the label, like `w-64` or with `flex`. That way, it will always stay that width, no matter the font weight. But with this you may run into other problems.

What I usually do, instead of changing the font weight to make the text stand out, is changing the color of the text. So the text may always be `font-semi-bold`, but unchecked it is `text-slate-500` and checked it is `text-indigo-700`.

Hope this helps.